# Using Photon real-time with .NET having connection problem

Tags: c#, .net, photon

I'm trying to connect to Photon using PlayFab access token and app ID in my windows form application. But every time connection status stuck at "ConnectingtoNameServer", i didn't find enough threads on the internet to solve this problem. Here is my code :

```
LoadBalancingClient lbclient = new LoadBalancingClient( "us",PAppID,"1.0",ExitGames.Client.Photon.ConnectionProtocol.Udp);
lbclient.AuthValues = new Photon.Realtime.AuthenticationValues();
lbclient.AuthValues.AuthType = Photon.Realtime.CustomAuthenticationType.Custom;
lbclient.AuthValues.AddAuthParameter("username", PlayfabIDUSer);                       
lbclient. AuthValues.AddAuthParameter("token", tok);                        
lbclient.AuthValues.UserId = PlayfabIDUSer;                        
lbclient.NameServerHost = "ns.exitgames.com";                        
lbclient.ConnectToRegionMaster("eu");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `lbclient.Service()` periodically in your main/game loop (like a "message pump").
You could do it in a background thread or task.

Read more [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/realtime/current/getting-started/realtime-intro#call_service) and [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/realtime/current/reference/performance-tips#call_service_regularly).